# Add field in RETURNS TABLE pgplsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How to add a field in the RETURNS TABLE of a plpgpsql function, the value I want to add is not present in the SELECT performed inside the function :

I have this function that samples the sum of cpu and ram used by jobs every 'step' seconds between start_date and end_date (epoch timestamp):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resources(start_date INTEGER, end_date INTEGER, step INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE (
    cpu bigint
  , ram bigint)  AS $$
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0 ;
BEGIN
  counter := start_date;
  LOOP 
    EXIT WHEN counter > end_date ;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    'SELECT sum(j_ram) as ram, sum(j_cpu) as cpu from jobs where j_start_time <= ' || counter || ' and j_end_time >= ' || counter;
    counter := counter + step ; 
  END LOOP ; 

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The outputed results is something like :

```
 cpu   |  ram 
-------+------
     0 |      
     6 | 12000
     6 | 11000
     1 | 1000
```

How to add the value of the variable 'counter' in the table to have something like :

```
 cpu   |  ram  | counter 
-------+-------+--------
     0 |       |     100        
     6 | 12000 |     110      
     6 | 11000 |     120       
     1 |  1000 |     130
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need `EXECUTE` for your case as there's no dynamic parameter like tablename, column name etc. It's only the value passed to where clause that changes. The counter can be part of select.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resources(start_date INTEGER, end_date INTEGER, 
step INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE (
    cpu bigint
  , ram bigint
  , counter int)  AS $$
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0 ;
BEGIN
  counter := start_date;
  LOOP 
    EXIT WHEN counter > end_date ;
RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT sum(j_ram)::bigint as ram, sum(j_cpu)::bigint as cpu,
           counter from jobs 
        where j_start_time <= counter
    and  j_end_time >= counter;
    counter := counter + step ; 
  END LOOP ; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would recommend you to avoid loops, a single query using `generate_series` would be good enough.The function can then be a simple **SQL function** unless you have anything else to do than return just a query result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resources2(start_date INTEGER, end_date INTEGER, 
step INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE (
    cpu bigint
  , ram bigint
  , counter int)  AS $$
   SELECT sum(j_ram) :: BIGINT AS ram, 
         sum(j_cpu) :: BIGINT AS cpu, 
       g.counter 
    FROM   jobs j 
       JOIN (SELECT generate_series(start_date, end_date, step) AS counter) g 
         ON j_start_time <= g.counter 
            AND j_end_time >= g.counter 
   GROUP  BY g.counter 
    ORDER  BY g.counter; 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ba5707cc9f458863dfaf91bcd6702412)

Comment: The second function can even be `language sql` not need for PL/pgSQL there

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now, the only downside is that if the "select from jobs" does not return any jobs i won't have the entry for the current counter

Comment: With the solution using LOOP I have a line when no jobs is selected (thus cpu/ram is 0 ). The solution with generate_series seems cleaner though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for dynamic SQL here. And if you leave that out, you can simply add the variable to the select:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resources(start_date INTEGER, end_date INTEGER, step INTEGER) 
  RETURNS TABLE (
      cpu bigint
    , ram bigint 
    , counter bigint)  
AS $$

DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  counter := start_date;
  LOOP 
    EXIT WHEN counter > end_date;

    RETURN QUERY 
      SELECT sum(j_ram) as ram, sum(j_cpu) as cpu, counter 
      from jobs 
      where j_start_time <= counter 
        and j_end_time >= counter;

    counter := counter + step; 
  END LOOP; 

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```